# Access to network drive using java

Tags: java, file, io

I do not have access to network drive but when I am trying to access a file from network drive it is not giving any exception and returning false when I am checking file exist

on the other hand for local drive it is working properly.

question here, why I am not getting exception "Access denied" when I have do not have access

Am I using correct syntax for accessing network drive?

```html
public class Check {

    private static final String networkDrivePath = "Y:/Nyk/Users/Shared/test.txt";

    private static final String localpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/Pr/test.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args){


        File f1 =  new File(networkDrivePath);
        System.out.println(f1.exists());


        File f3 =  new File(localpath);
        System.out.println(f3.exists());


    }

}
```

Output of above program

false

true

Comment: question here why I am not getting exception "Access denied" when I have do not have access

Comment: Are you expecting to get an error when you create the `new File(networkDrivePath)` ? If so, that's not how it works : as the javadoc mentions, `File` are "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames." and can represent inexistant or inaccessible paths.

Comment: I haven't got a network drive handy, but I think you could probably use `new File("Y:/").canRead()` to test whether you currently have access to your network drive.

Comment: I guess you could use Security manager: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html
And use the checkread to check for acces to folder.

Comment: got it ...Thanks for all above reply :)

Comment: I don't think that the security manager helps.  Unless you've actually configured file access policies in your JVM.

Comment: The real problem here is that the OS is not able to distinguish (and report) the real reason why you cannot access a particular file on the network drive.  Specifically it can't distinguish between "you don't have access to thing" and "I don 't know this thing you are asking about".  And if the OS doesn't tell Java, then Java can't tell your application code.

Comment: (And then there is "I cannot confirm or deny that thing exists" because you don't have sufficient access to know that.  Security / access control models get in the way of explaining to the end user what the real problem is.)